# How do I find $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$ > 0 for functions of two variables?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I had the following question on my worksheet.

> Each of the following exercises gives a function f(x,y) and a positive number ε. In each exercise, show that there exists a $\delta$ > 0 such that for all $(x, y)$, $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ < $\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f(x,y)−f(0,0)| < \epsilon$.

> i. $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2, \epsilon = 0.01$

> ii. $f(x, y) = \frac{y}{x^2 + 1}, \epsilon = 0.05$

> iii. $f(x, y) = \frac{x+y}{x^2+1}, \epsilon = 0.01$

> iv. $f(x, y) = \frac{x+y}{2+\cos{x}}, \epsilon = 0.02$

I was able to do the first and second question fairly easily. But, I'm facing difficulty on solving the other two. I tried using a lot of inequalities to convert one of the inequality to the other but I have reached nowhere whereas those techniques worked in solving the first two questions. Can anyone assist me in understanding how to solve the other two?

Comment: **HINT**: Can you make $|x+y|<\epsilon$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's compute $f(0, 0)$:
$
f(0, 0) = \frac{0 + 0}{0^2 + 1} = \frac{0}{1} = 0
$

Now, we need to bound the expression $|f(x, y) - f(0, 0)|$ and simplify it in terms of $\epsilon$:

$
|f(x, y) - f(0, 0)| = \left|\frac{x + y}{x^2 + 1} - 0\right| = \left|\frac{x + y}{x^2 + 1}\right|
$

We want to make this less than $\epsilon$, which is 0.01. So, we have:

$
\left|\frac{x + y}{x^2 + 1}\right| < 0.01
$

Now, we need to find a bound for $x + y$ in terms of $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Using the triangle inequality, we have:

$
|x + y| \leq |x| + |y| \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}
$

So,

$
\frac{2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x^2 + 1} < 0.01
$

Now, we need to isolate $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and find $\delta$:

$
\frac{2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x^2 + 1} < 0.01
$

$
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \frac{(x^2 + 1)(0.01)}{2}
$

Now, we can choose $\delta = 0.005\epsilon$. If $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta$, then:

$
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 0.005\epsilon
$

$
x^2 + 1 > 0 \quad \text{(because it's always positive)}
$

Now, let's prove the original statement:

If $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta$, then:

$
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 0.005\epsilon
$

$
x^2 + 1 > 0
$

Therefore:

$
\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{x^2 + 1} < 0.005\epsilon
$

Which is what we wanted to prove. So, for $\epsilon = 0.01$, there exists a $\delta = 0.005\epsilon$ such that for all $(x, y)$, if $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < \delta$, then $|f(x, y) - f(0, 0)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I think you need $x^2+1 \ge 1$, not $x^2 + 1 > 0$?